# How to add url string to mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I've created a front end table with the following code. It's working great. But what I want to do is add a link to member's profiles based on their user_id. We view member profiles by visiting http://example.com/profile/?profile=642 (642 being the user_id) So, I want to add "http://example.com/profile/?profile=" in front of the m4.user_id in my table. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
SELECT
DISTINCT
    u1.id,
    u1.user_login,
    u1.user_registered,
    u1.user_email,
    u1.user_url,
    m1.meta_value AS firstname,
    m2.meta_value AS lastname,
    m3.meta_value AS mepr_region,
 m4.user_id,
 t1.status,
 t2.expires_at
FROM wp_acfzia_users u1
JOIN wp_acfzia_usermeta m1 ON (m1.user_id = u1.id AND m1.meta_key = 'first_name')
JOIN wp_acfzia_usermeta m2 ON (m2.user_id = u1.id AND m2.meta_key = 'last_name')
JOIN wp_acfzia_usermeta m3 ON (m3.user_id = u1.id AND m3.meta_key = 'mepr_region')
JOIN wp_acfzia_usermeta m4 ON (m4.user_id = u1.id) 
JOIN wp_acfzia_mepr_transactions t1 ON (t1.id = u1.id)
JOIN wp_acfzia_mepr_transactions t2 ON (t2.id = u1.id)
WHERE m3.meta_value = 'aimga-south'
```

Comment: you could just concatenate the link and the id in your select concat("http://example.com/profile/?profile=", m4.user_id)

Answer (score 4):

Use Mysql's `CONCAT` function to concatenate two strings:

```
SELECT
    m4.user_id,
    CONCAT('http://example.com/profile/?profile=', m4.user_id) as profile_url
...
```

Mysql will automatically cast your id integer to a string to concatenate.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a million. Works perfectly

Comment: @gormant Great! Feel free to hit the checkbox to accept the answer :)